# Selenium(Java) - Get URL to open for WebDriver from csv or txt file

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bufferedreader

I have a file with about 50 rows which contain URLs and i want to open them with webdriver one by one. is this possible?i have tried the below but getting invalid argument error.

```
public static void readFile() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String fileName = "/mypath/uk_as/urls.csv";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
          for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            driver.get(line);
          }
        }
        
    }
```